# C convention - Adding H files to project file

Tags: c, conventions

A friend at work told me today that

> It is a known convention to **not add** header files to the project file in C project.

I was shocked and couldn't find any logical reason for this(because I felt that this convention would just make it difficult to reach the file I need).

He explained it as that the H file doesn't really contain compilable C code, so it is not "part of the project", but just meta data.

FYI - we work currently on an embedded project.

For example - project file could be - eww file with IAR workbench, or vcxproj in visual studio, or cproject file with eclipse

Does any one ever encountered this kind of convention, and could say how popular is it and what is the practical advantage/logic of it?

Comment: Care to explain what a project file is?

Comment: Are you talking about [msdn project files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2208a1f2.aspx) or something else? You might want some more tags or information to this question to cover your IDE, because the answer might be specific to that.

Comment: Contents of .h files most certainly are C code, as they are `#include`d (effecively equal to "copy-pasted" with C preprosessor...) in .c files and those would not compile if .h files didn't contain valid C code.

Comment: @larsmans - edited with examples

Comment: Your friend and you are talking about two separate things; you are talking about IDE specific project files (e.g. MS VC) whereas your friend is talking about makefiles. Both serve similar purposes but take different approaches.

Comment: @Mike - yes, for example msdn project files. I added examples in the questions

Comment: Short answer: it depends on the kind of project file, there's no such general rule.

Comment: @Till - you are wrong, the first question I asked him is if he ment to makefiles. He answered  "makefiles are example, but it is true for every project file" and was very clear it is about IDE project files

Comment: @hyde - for example - what kind of project file would be eligible for such convention? (except make file)

Comment: @YoavR. Actually, Makefiles often have .h files listed as dependencies for .c files (the list is often generated, but for small projects it may be hand-written), so that when .h files change, all the necessary .c files get re-compiled. Without such deps, a clean rebuild would be needed after any .h file changes.

Comment: @hyde - correct - Just thought about it

Comment: @YoavR. Updated my answer to list why such a convention (not having .h files in project files) might make sense.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this is a convention. Header files **describe the interfaces between parts of your program**, which I would argue is more important than the specific bits of code for many projects. If you move into C++, you may also find significant portions of the project's code implemented in headers to support templates in older C++ versions.

Your IDE is meant to keep the code you're using front and center, so you can access the source that you need and edit any code while minimizing context switching.

My advice: Add the headers to your project, but categorize them in a separate folder, filter group, or other mechanism to make them easy to access. Make sure they're visible to the compiler, set their build targets to not compile (since they're just being included) and you should be set.

Answer (score 1):

There are no disadvantages of adding a header file to the project.

Some advantages I find:

- If I create 'Source Files' , 'Header Files' etc folders and and add the respective files to the folder,it looks neat when you open the project in your IDE as I can directly see what are the header files being used in my project (which most of the times are created by you)
- In some IDEs (eg MSVC) , I can search the header file directly using the search window if that header file has been added to the project.Otherwise I need to open one of the C/C++ files which includes this header and has to open the file from the line where #include is defined for that file.

So it is upto you , whether you need everything organized . depending your IDE etc , you can add/exclude header files to the project.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I can think of to not include .h files in your project file is if they aren't a part of your project. For example `stdio.h`. I have seen people do this before and it can cause problems. The main issue is that is can make your project non-portable. It can also lead to people accidentally modifying files that they shouldn't.

Is it possible that's what your friend was talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, looks like one counter-example is enough to show that *.h* files are sometimes included in project files. Here's an example of a Qt *qmake* *.pro* file for a project, which lists header files:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.c \
    module.c

HEADERS += \
    module.h
```

To get that, I used *Qt Creator* first to create the project as "plain C project", then generated the `module.h` and the `module.c` stubs with Qt Creator, which added both to the *.pro* file. Now having the *.h* files in the *.pro* is optional: project would compile without it, but it would be harder to navigate the project etc, and I'd have to manually remove each *.h* from *.pro* after generating them.

---

As a complete opposite, I think there are build systems (with their project files) also for C projects, where you don't actually need to list *any* files. You just list directories, or even have standard directory layout, and the build system will scan the directories and compile the project according to it's rules. I think this is possible with cmake at least. And of course for many project file types (like plain Makefiles) you can use wildcards to find all .c files in a directory.

---

As to reasons why .h files would not be listed:

- Compiler will find the .h files based on `#include`s, they are not given in command line (only include directories are given).
- A modern IDE will scan the sources anyway and find all the used include files without them being listed.
- If .h file lists are maintained manually, but per above two points nothing will actually fail if one is forgotten, then the list in project file may get out of date, when someone just forgets either to add or remove one when there are changes.
- Listing build dependencies for each .c file is actually a bit different than just listing the .h files in project files, and is best handled automatically.
- Using a version control should remove any ambiguity between files which are really part of the project even if they are not used (because they are in version control), and which are just some clutter which should be removed/ignored.

So, if *having* .h files listed in a project file is any extra work, and if it does not offer any concrete advantage (for example with some IDE), then a convention of just not having them seems sensible.